# Error : How to write getHistoryForKey() method in hyperledger chaincode to get history for a key (java language)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, smartcontracts, hyperledger-chaincode, chaincode

**I have written following method into my hyperledger chaincode (smart contract)  to get history (all transaction data) based on a key,**

```java
@Transaction(intent = Transaction.TYPE.EVALUATE)
public ArrayList<String> queryProductHistory(final Context ctx, final String productNumber) {
    if (productNumber == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("No ID given");
    }

    ChaincodeStub stub = ctx.getStub();
    ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        QueryResultsIterator<KeyModification> history = stub.getHistoryForKey(productNumber);

        if (history == null) {
            String errorMessage = String.format("Product %s does not exist", productNumber);
            System.out.println(errorMessage);
            throw new ChaincodeException(errorMessage, MySmartContractErrors.PRODUCT_NOT_FOUND.toString());
        }

        Iterator<KeyModification> iter = history.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            results.add(iter.next().getStringValue());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        results.add(e.getMessage());
        results.add(e.getCause().getMessage());
        results.add(e.getStackTrace().toString());
    }

    return results;
}
```

**I have also written one API for above method,**

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "find-product-history", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String queryProductHistory(@RequestParam(value="channelName") String channelName, @RequestParam(value="productNumber") String productNumber) throws Exception {

    // Load a file system based wallet for managing identities.
    Path walletPath = Paths.get("wallet");
    Wallet wallet = Wallets.newFileSystemWallet(walletPath);

    // load a CCP
    Path networkConfigPath = Paths.get("/home", "ubuntu", "fabric-samples", "test-network", "organizations", "peerOrganizations", "org1.example.com", "connection-org1.yaml");
    Gateway.Builder builder = Gateway.createBuilder();
    builder.identity(wallet, "appUser").networkConfig(networkConfigPath).discovery(true);

    // create a gateway connection
    try (Gateway gateway = builder.connect()) {

        // get the network and contract
        Network network = gateway.getNetwork(channelName);
        Contract contract = network.getContract("my-blockchain-smart-contract");
        byte[] result;
        result = contract.evaluateTransaction("queryProductHistory", productNumber);
        System.out.println(new String(result));
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

**I am getting following error. What may be wrong here?**

```
org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.ContractException: error in simulation: transaction returned with failure: Unexpected error
at org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.impl.query.SingleQueryHandler.evaluate(SingleQueryHandler.java:50) ~[fabric-gateway-java-2.1.1.jar:na]
at org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.impl.TransactionImpl.evaluate(TransactionImpl.java:207) ~[fabric-gateway-java-2.1.1.jar:na]
at org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.impl.ContractImpl.evaluateTransaction(ContractImpl.java:55) ~[fabric-gateway-java-2.1.1.jar:na]
at com.my.blockchain.api.controller.BlockchainAPIController.queryProductHistory(BlockchainAPIController.java:137) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1061) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_275]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_275]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_275]
```

***Note : I have done `enableHistoryDatabase: true` in the core.xml as well***

Answer (score 0):

It works fine now.
Here is the correction in chaincode `queryProductHistory()` method

```
@Transaction
    public String queryProductHistory(final Context ctx, final String productNumber) {
        if (productNumber == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No ID given");
        }
        ChaincodeStub stub = ctx.getStub();
        ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            QueryResultsIterator<KeyModification> history = stub.getHistoryForKey(productNumber);
            
            if (history == null) {
                String errorMessage = String.format("Product %s does not exist", productNumber);
                System.out.println(errorMessage);
                throw new ChaincodeException(errorMessage, MySmartContractErrors.PRODUCT_NOT_FOUND.toString());
            }
            Iterator<KeyModification> iterator = history.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                String iteratorValue = iterator.next().getStringValue();
                //String iteratorValue = "TIMESTAMP = " + iterator.next().getTimestamp() + "Tx ID = " + iterator.next().getTxId() + " VALUE = " + iterator.next().getStringValue();
                results.add(iteratorValue);
                
                System.out.println(iteratorValue);
            }
            history.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            results.add(e.getMessage());
            results.add(e.getCause().getMessage());
            results.add(e.getStackTrace().toString());
        }
        return results.toString();
    }
```

And here is API service `queryProductHistory()` method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "find-product-history", method = RequestMethod.GET) public String queryProductHistory(@RequestParam(value="channelName") String channelName, @RequestParam(value="productNumber") String productNumber) throws Exception {

    // Load a file system based wallet for managing identities.
    Path walletPath = Paths.get("wallet");
    Wallet wallet = Wallets.newFileSystemWallet(walletPath);
    // load a CCP
    Path networkConfigPath = Paths.get("/home", "ubuntu", "fabric-samples", "test-network", "organizations", "peerOrganizations",
            "org1.example.com", "connection-org1.yaml");

    Gateway.Builder builder = Gateway.createBuilder();
    builder.identity(wallet, "appUser").networkConfig(networkConfigPath).discovery(true);

    // create a gateway connection
    try (Gateway gateway = builder.connect()) {

        // get the network and contract
        Network network = gateway.getNetwork(channelName);
        Contract contract = network.getContract("my-blockchain-smart-contract");

        byte[] result;

        result = contract.evaluateTransaction("queryProductHistory", productNumber);
        //result = contract.submitTransaction("queryProductHistory", productNumber);

        System.out.println(new String(result));

        return new String(result);
    }
}
```